# Is there a way of stopping a function after a delay? Nodejs

Tags: node.js, function, delay, abort

Is it possible to abort a function after a delay? Something like:

```
function f() {
    //Do some process here
}

after(10000).stop(f)
```

Any idea about how to do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cluster module like this

```
const cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    const fn = cluster.fork();
    setTimeout(_=>fn.process.kill(), 300);
} else {
    for(;;) {
       process.stdout.write('#');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your function inside a function that checks for the time.

```
function stopExecutingAfter(timeout, fn) {
  var stopifAfter = Date.now() + timeout
  return function() {
    if(Date.now() > stopIfAfter) return
    fn.apply(null, arguments)
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working, function stopExecutingAfter(timeout, fn) {
  let stopIfAfter = Date.now() + timeout
  return function() {
    if(Date.now() > stopIfAfter) return
    fn.apply(null, arguments)
  }
}

function something() {
  let i = 0
  while(true)
    console.log('Testng kill ' + i++)
}

stopExecutingAfter(1000, something)()

Answer (score 0):

So we will have library killer.js

```
const cluster = require('cluster');

module.exports = (fn, delay) => {
    if (cluster.isMaster) {
        const fn = cluster.fork();
        setTimeout(_=>fn.process.kill(), delay);
    } else {
        fn();
    }
}
```

And example for using it

```
const killer = require('./killer');

function fn() {
    for(;;) process.stdout.write('#');
}

killer(fn, 100);
```